# Code Missing Expression or Not Working

Tags: javascript

I have another post out there, but I am missing something in this code and it's not working. Need a PRO to look at my mickey-mouse script and help me execute it.

Site can be located at https://wbtfoundation.org - top bar has city geolocation (e.g. Rockwall, Texas | United States (this is the storeID)

Based on div storeID (geolocation populated)

```
CSS

.ACTIVE-CodeClass {display:none} //active banner
.DEFAULT-CodeClass {display:none} //default banner



HTML

<div class="ACTIVE-CodeClass" id="ACTIVE-CodeClass">
   <a href="/store-find/" title="">
      <picture class="" id="">       
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="2020/UAT/ACTIVE-BANNER-D.jpg?$staticlink$" media="(min-width: 768px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img src="2020/UAT/ACTIVE-BANNER-D.jpg?$staticlink$"     alt="">
      </picture>
    </a>
</div>

<div class="DEFAULT-CodeClass" id="DEFAULT-CodeClass">
   <a href="/store-find/" title="">
      <picture class="" id="">       
        <!--[if IE 9]><video style="display: none;"><![endif]-->
        <source srcset="2020/UAT/DEFAULT-BANNER-D.jpg?$staticlink$" media="(min-width: 768px)">
        <!--[if IE 9]></video><![endif]-->
        <img src="2020/UAT/DEFAULT-BANNER-D.jpg?$staticlink$"     alt="">
      </picture>
    </a>
</div>


JS

$( document ).ready(function() {
let storeID = itemStore (); 

// find region
var itemStore=['Rockwall', 'Dallas', 'Travis', 'Hunt', 'Tarrant', 'Houston', 'Gainsville'];
$(itemStore).each(function(){
  if ($('#storeID').text().indexOf(this) != -1) {

// execute active region banner 
var customerStore = itemStore;  // Test Store
var storeOcapiUrl = '/s/athome-sfra/dw/shop/v20_4/stores/' + customerStore;

$.ajax({
   url: storeOcapiUrl,
   data: {
     client_id: 'a9392000-57a9-46a4-bd86-78c5ff617795'
   },
   success: function(storeData){
   console.log(storeData);
   if ( storeData.c_enablePickup && storeData.c_enableDelivery ) {
     // show active storeBanner
     $('.ACTIVE-CodeClass').show();
   } else if (storeStatus && storeData == null) {
     // show a default storeBanner
     $('.DEFAULT-CodeClass').show();
   }
} 
});
```